# Select all records of one table that contain two records in another with certain id

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables of 1:m relation. Need to select which People records have both records in Actions table whit id 1 and 2

```
People
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name | phone_number |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | John | 111111111111 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | Jane | 222222222222 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 4  | Jack | 333333333333 |
+----+------+--------------+

Action
+----+------+------------+
| id | PplId| ActionId   |
+----+------+------------+
| 1  |   1  |      1     |
+----+------+------------+
| 2  |   1  |      2     |
+----+------+------------+
| 3  |   2  |      1     |
+----+------+------------+
| 4  |   4  |      2     |
+----+------+------------+

Output
+----+------+--------------+----------
|PplId| name | Phone       |ActionId |
+-----+------+-------------+----+-----
| 1   | John | 111111111111|   1     |
+-----+------+-------------+----+-----
| 1   | John | 111111111111|   2     |
+-----+------+-------------+----+-----
```

Return records of People that have both  Have Actionid 1 and Action id 2(Have records in Actions).

Answer (score 1):

Window functions are one method.  Assuming actions are not duplicated for a person:

```
select pa.*
from (select p.*, a.action, count(*) over (partition by p.id) as num_actions
      from people p join
           action a
           on p.id = a.pplid
      where a.action in (1, 2)
     ) pa
where num_actions = 2;
```

In my opinion, getting two rows with the action detail seems superfluous -- you already know the actions.  If you only want the people, then `exists` comes to mind:

```
select p.*
from people p
where exists (select 1 from actions where a.pplid = p.id and a.action = 1) and
      exists (select 1 from actions where a.pplid = p.id and a.action = 2);
```

With the right index (`actions(pplid, action)`), I would expect two `exists` to be faster than `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query using subquery and join

```
select a.Pplid, name, phone, actionid from (
select a.pplid as Pplid, name, phone_number as phone
from People P
join Action A on a.pplid= p.id
group by a.pplid, name, phone_number
having count(*)>1 )P
join Action A on a.Pplid= p.Pplid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#People') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #People
CREATE TABLE #People (id INT, name VARCHAR(255), phone_number VARCHAR(50))
INSERT #People
SELECT 1, 'John', '111111111111' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Jane', '222222222222' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Jack', '333333333333' 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Action') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Action
CREATE TABLE #Action (id INT, PplId INT, ActionId INT)
INSERT #Action
SELECT 1, 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 2
GO

SELECT      p.ID                AS PplId
            , p.name
            , p.phone_number    AS Phone
            , a.ActionId
FROM        #People p
JOIN        #Action a
ON          p.ID = a.PplId
WHERE       p.ID IN (   SELECT      PplId 
                        FROM        #Action
                        WHERE       ActionId IN (1, 2) 
                        GROUP BY    PplId
                        HAVING      COUNT(*) = 2    )
            AND a.ActionId IN (1, 2)
GO
```